# Is there a way to configure Jackson deserialization error messages to remove references to the object?

Tags: java, json, jackson

We're using Jackson for deserialization, but occasionally we have an edge case (usually a bug) where we'll try to feed an invalid string in for deserialization and Jackson will throw an exception like `MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of 'java.lang.String' out of START_OBJECT token\n at {'key':'value'}`. This last portion is the part we are having some issue with. We currently log this exception message as is (in particular because we don't really expect it to come up under normal circumstances), but this presents an issue because we don't want to log the object value (eg. `{'key':'value'}`). Is there any way to configure Jackson to just not include the object as part of the exception message?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to do it via Jackson itself but, if it can be of any help, to avoid printing sensitive data you can try to configure the default logger directly. For example in my project I'm using Log4j2 and because I don't want a bearer token to be printed in the logs I have added to my log4j2.properties file the following:

```
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=%-5p %c: %replace{%m}{(([bB][eE][aA][rR][eE][rR]).*)}{(Hidden)}%n%rEx
```

The only problem is that wherever the pattern is matched, the whole line will be replaced... with (Hidden) in this example.

In any case you should be able to specify more/less complex matching RegEx.

Comment: Hmmm yeah this may be an option, I just wish there were a more consistent way to identify sensitive data in logs. The OP has one example but we've seen this other times from jackson and I'm not sure there's one definitive way to identify a log that contains sensitive information. Still worth looking into, thanks!